# How to determine which subnet I am in on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-marketplace

When [starting an EC2 from an image in AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-gpjb3cd2aemaw), it requests Subnet Settings:

[image]

And says:

> Ensure you are in the selected VPC above

It gives 2 options:

[image]

I am not sure what this means.

Is it asking me to identify which AWS "subnet" (in this case either `ap-southeast-2b` or `ap-southeast-2a`) that my laptop is currently in, and tell AWS via this drop down? I don't understand why it would want this information, nor what to give it. I've used thousands of EC2s and never needed to specify anything more granular than `region`. But today I am starting the EC2 from a marketplace image and it requires this additional information.

Comment: "I've used thousands of EC2s and never needed to specify anything more granular than region" - what do you mean? You always choose VPC and subnet for an instance. Maybe you've just been accepting default ones?

Comment: @Marcin I suspect so. But now the UI is forcing me to select something specific, and because it’s never required that before, it’s not clear how. I have never needed to know about subnets to run jobs on EC2’s

Comment: So check any of your other instances, and see which subnet and vpc they use. And use the same one.

Comment: @Marcin okay I’ll try that. I suspect the marketplace image has placed some constrains on these values somehow (otherwise, why wouldn’t it just let me select defaults like every other time). I’m just guessing though.

Comment: But generally it is worth nowing your VPC and subnets. Default VPC and subnets are usually public ones. But often you may need to launch instances in private subnets for security reasons.

Comment: Please note that it is not asking which subnet your laptop is in. It is asking for a subnet to use when launching an Amazon EC2 instance using the Marketplace image.

Comment: @Marcin I will have to do some more reading. I’m a little concerned I’ll end up going down a rabbit hole and won’t emerge for days/weeks. If you know of any great 101 guides/videos/tutorials please link.

Comment: @stevec - FWIW, I get exactly the same VPC and subnet options, whether I launched AWS EC2, or this RStudio EC2. No difference! And I get an option of "no preference" in the list of subnets

Comment: @Felix "no preference"  means it will just choose a random subnet from the given VPC.

Comment: @Marcin - I know. But OP is surprised that such option doesn't exist, and he has to explicitly choose the subnet. And also the screenshot doesn't have such option!

Comment: @Marcin thanks a lot for following up. I never got it working. I have been in contact with RStudio (maintainer of the image) since 1 month ago (see [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-log-in-to-aws-rstudio-server-and-workbench-instead-see-error-unauthorized-user/126381)). They have forwarded through to their technical team. I ran out of time the other day but I will try to apply your advice to start and login to the image later today and update :)

Comment: @Marcin there's a non-trivial chance I've done something incorrectly when setting it up, or even that the image build or instructions have an omission or mistake. So I think this specific problem I'm having is most likely an issue with things unrelated to subnets specifically, and more to do with other parts of the image/instructions/execution.

Comment: @stevec Thanks. You can always make new questions if you have new issues with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are launching an instance, you have to choose a [VPC and a subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html). When you launch your instance, usually a [default VPC with default subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html) are pre-selected.

The default VPC and subnets are usually **public**, which makes your instances accessible from the internet. Often, for security reasons, it may not be desired. In that case a [custom VPC and/or subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-vpcs.html) are created. This allows you to create **private subnets** shielded from direct access from the internet. One such architecture is [VPC with public and private subnets (NAT)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html).

The NAT in the above setups allows instances in private subnets to access internet, without allowing direct access to the instances from the internet.